# Unable to View Local .Net Core ASP Application

Tags: iis, localhost, asp.net, core

## Scenario

Attempting to view locally published .Net Core ASP application from local *inetpub/wwwroot/* directory.

### Issue

Able to view application on laptop (just fine), however, not able to view the same application (same commit) on my primary workstation. All security privileges appear to be *identical*, while the application (itself) is setup within the same IIS application pool on both systems. *Looking for various tools that could assist me in troubleshooting this issue further.*

### Process

Navigate to local application at *http://localhost/* after publication.

#### Result(s)

> **Workstation**

```
  Error: HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error

  Message: The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid.

  Error Code: 0x8007000d
```

[View Image](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1GCXirosp7VnetK6baHQVO_5rE95QIjSl/view?usp=sharing)

> **Laptop**

```
  Error: None
```

*Works fine!*

## Environmental & Application Details

Local machine configuration(s)

### Security Privileges for *inetpub/wwwroot* (on both machines)

```
  CREATOR OWNER                SP

  SYSTEM            F M RX R W SP

  Administrators    F M RX R W

  Users                 RX R

  IIS_IUSRS             RX R

  TrustedInstaller  F M RX R W
```

### Security Privileges for *inetpub/wwwroot/* (on both machines)

```
  Everyone          F M RX R W

  CREATOR OWNER                SP

  IUSR              F M RX R W

  SYSTEM            F M RX R W

  Administrators    F M RX R W SP

  Users             F M RX R W

  IIS_IUSRS         F M RX R W

  TrustedInstaller  F M RX R W
```

### Publication Methodology

```
  Publish Method: File System
```

[View Image](https://drive.google.com/file/d/11Um2MxiBsTTEQxm-3t27RpJ1KCUyUT5t/view?usp=sharing)

```
  Publish Configuration: Release

  Target Framework: netcoreapp2.1

  Deployment Mode: Framework-Dependent

  Target Runtime: Portable
```

[View Image](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ZLyxqTMLDFW3TzQMnlsXGGihTJ0V_cKO/view?usp=sharing)

### Wireshark Inspection

```
  No.   Time    Source  Destination Protocol Length  Info
  -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  1     0          ::1          ::1 HTTP        533  GET /Portfolio HTTP/1.1
  2     0.000125   ::1          ::1 TCP          74  80  >  56028 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=460 Win=2068 Len=0
  3     0.001568   ::1          ::1 TCP        1514  80  >  56028 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=460 Win=2068 Len=1440 [TCP segment of a reassembled PDU]
  4     0.001577   ::1          ::1 TCP        1514  80  >  56028 [ACK] Seq=1441 Ack=460 Win=2068 Len=1440 [TCP segment of a reassembled PDU]
  5     0.001612   ::1          ::1 TCP        1514  80  >  56028 [ACK] Seq=2881 Ack=460 Win=2068 Len=1440 [TCP segment of a reassembled PDU]
  6     0.001619   ::1          ::1 HTTP        514  HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error  (text/html)
  7     0.001733   ::1          ::1 TCP          74  56028  >  80 [ACK] Seq=460 Ack=4761 Win=2070 Len=0
  8     4.155498   ::1          ::1 TCP          74  56029  >  80 [FIN, ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=2070 Len=0
  9     4.155603   ::1          ::1 TCP          74  80  >  56029 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=2 Win=2070 Len=0
  10    4.155654   ::1          ::1 TCP          74  80  >  56029 [RST, ACK] Seq=1 Ack=2 Win=0 Len=0
```

[View Image](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1MbKbB2loMWQhewCDJN7V_H-zx3jGz2xP/view?usp=sharing)

## Attempted Solutions

- Installed URL Rewrite
- No Antiviral Software Operating on Either Machine

Comment: I am unable to access the images on your Google drive.  Please upload them to imgur instead.  This will also allow the image to always be accessible even after it's removed from your account.

Answer (score 0):

Error code [0x8007000d](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/942055/http-error-500-19-error-when-you-open-an-iis-7-0-webpage) tells us, that file contains a malformed XML element.
And your Config Source shows, that problem is between -1 and 0 lines (first 3 bytes of BOM-header).

If the `web.config` file has a [BOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) set, then the XML root node `encoding` attribute must match.

Check the encoding of your's `web.config` file or try to ReSave it without BOM-header.

[VSCode save with encoding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AB7I6.gif)